# WSO2 Programmatically Update an Endpoint Configuration

Tags: wso2, updates, endpoint, wso2-esb

I wrote these code lines for accessing and modifying programmatically the load balanced endpoint configurations saved in my esb (4.7.0) local registry. [in a few words i add a new address endpoint to the load balance endpoint list]

```
    SynapseConfiguration sc = synapseMsgContext.getConfiguration();

    LoadbalanceEndpoint le =(LoadbalanceEndpoint) sc.getEndpoint("test");       
    List<Endpoint>list = le.getChildren();
    AddressEndpoint ad = new AddressEndpoint();
    EndpointDefinition  def = new EndpointDefinition();        
    def.setAddress("http://172.17.54.101:8083/RestService/rest/servizio");
    def.setAddressingOn(false);
    def.setTimeoutAction(100);
    ad.setDefinition(def);
    list.add(ad);
    le.setChildren(list);
    sc.updateEndpoint("test", le);
    synapseMsgContext.setConfiguration(sc);
```

By this code lines the endpoint's updates are held in memory and lost when i restart the ESB. So this update lastes only till the esb is stopped.

How can i make these updates persistent? I mean an effective update on the endpoint xml configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

You have to check endpoint serilaizer and factory.
http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/dependencies/synapse/2.1.2-wso2v3/modules/core/src/main/java/org/apache/synapse/config/xml/endpoints/

Comment: I've checked the EndpointFactory and EndpointSerializer. But i don't find anything could help me. The endpoint factory allows me to create a new endpoint (i already do this) and che serializer allows me to serialize into xml element. Ok but i need to invoke the same function i use on the UI when i click on Save&Close after i created or modified a new endpoint. Could you suggest me it? i should have to see my endpoint config file updated on the filesystem.

Comment: You can simply use EndpointAdmin service to persist your configuration to the filesystem.
http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/components/endpoint/org.wso2.carbon.endpoint/4.2.0/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/endpoint/service/EndpointAdmin.java

Comment: That is the admin service, we use from the UI to persist the configuration..You can have your own logic, else write a client for that Admin service and use it

Comment: great... found the saveEnpoint function inside EndpoinAdmin. It works